# Docker compose does not create volume docker-entrypoint-initdb.d for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml` file, which generates a mongo and a mongo-express image:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.4
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodbtest
    ports:
       - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456789
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: experts
    volumes:
      - docker-data:/data/db
      - ./db-init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodbexpress
    depends_on:
        - mongo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123456789

volumes:
  docker-data:
    name: experts-mongoDB-data
```

In the folder `init-db/init.js` I have the following script:

```
db.createUser({
  user: "andrea",
  pwd: "123456789",
  roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "experts" } ]
})

db.experts.insert({
  name: "Steve Jobs"
})
```

Despite that, when I run `docker-compose up` the container is created but the database `experts` is not. Does anyone know where this problem lies? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: You called your folder `init-db` in your message but `db-init` in the volumes defined in your `docker-compose.yaml`. Can you make sure that they have the same name?

Comment: @NicolasB hello, you are right. I changed it but I still dont see the db

Comment: @NicolasB should I indicate somewhere/somehow that I want the file `init.js` to be used?